# BizTalk 2016 sFTP Adapter - Stops Working, until Host Instance Restarted

Tags: sftp, biztalk, winscp, biztalk-2016

We have a BizTalk 2016 FP3 and CU5 Enterprise Group with two app servers. There are three send ports that make use of the new sFTP adapter. Each of the send ports is configured to run on the same host instance, which is configured to run only on the first of the two app servers.

Everything works fine for a while, then after a few minutes minutes, the outbound messages start to back-up. When viewing running message instances in the BizTalk Admin Console, we can see they have a Status of "Active". There are no exceptions in the event log. We've configured the send ports to output to a log file too (log property of the sFTP adapter config), but no clues in there either.

When the host instance is re-started then the "Active" messages are quick processed, and all is good for the next fifteen minutes or so until problem issue repeats.

Anyone else come across this problem?

Comment: we use the same configuration and don't experienced this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away following a new deployment of the BizTalk solution that contained the problem send port. Very strange, since a comparison of bindings exported before and after gave no clues.